# Obtaining an array of json format question and put them into an array in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, json, object, arraylist

The goal here is to retrieve JSON format data from an API, convert the data into an array in android studio. Then to display a random question into a text view and the question will not repeat itself. The question changes everytime a button is clicked. There's something wrong with the logic of how I use my array/parsing the data to the array. I am not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated

MY JSON format

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Successfully retrieved",
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "Tell us about yourself?"
        },
        {
            "question": "Tell us about yourself2?"
        },
        {
            "question": "Tell us about yourself3?"
        },
        {
            "question": "Tell us about yourself4?"
        },
        {
            "question": "Tell us about yourself5?"
        }
    ]
}
```

My code so far ( simplified to this function )

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // create arraylist to store question
    List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    // use max to decide the number of question
    // use i to find out the number of questions
    int i = 10;
    int min = 0;
    int max = i;
    int[] usedInt = new int[max];
    //create another array to put all the used integer inside for 0 repeition of question
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView textViewQuestions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView);

        usedInt = new int[i];
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        //generate random number, set textview the question, set int to usedint array
        textViewQuestions.setText(questionList.get(i1));
        usedInt[0] = i1;

        //set first question

        findViewById(R.id.changeQuestion).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Log.d(TAG,questionList[updateQuestions(usedInt)]);
                //final int[] usedIntTemp = usedInt;

                getQuestions();
                int n = updateQuestions(usedInt);
                textViewQuestions.setText(questionList.get(n));
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }

    }

public int updateQuestions(int usedInteger[]) {
        int min = 0;
        int max = i;
        Random r = new Random();
        int i2 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int uInteger[] = usedInteger;
        int l = 0;

        while (l != max) {
            if (i2 == usedInteger[l]) {
                l++;
                if (l == max) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No other questions available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } else {
                usedInteger[usedInteger.length + 1] = i2;
                return i2;

            }


        }
        return i2;


    }
private void getQuestions()
    {

    class GetQuestions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        //private ProgressBar progressBar;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("role_id", "1");

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_QUESTIONS, params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
            //progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //hiding the progressbar after completion
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            boolean Error1 = false;
            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);


                //HashMap<String, String> questionJson = new HashMap<>();


                // success = obj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //getting the questions from the response
                    JSONArray questionsJson = obj.getJSONArray("questions");

                    //creating a new questions object

                    for (i = 0; i < questionsJson.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = questionsJson.getJSONObject(i);
                        questionList.add(object.getString("question"));
                        Log.d(TAG,"objcheck");
                        Log.d(TAG,object.getString("question"));

                        //q = c.getString("question");
                        //questionJson.put("question", q);
                        //questionList.add(questionJson);
                    }

                    finish();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
        GetQuestions gq = new GetQuestions();
        gq.execute();

}
```

Comment: remove the question that is displayed from list , so that while generating next question duplication won't occur

Comment: well, if remembered correctly if you remove the questions, but the number of which the array wont change, say you have array[0] = "abc" and array[1] = "def", if i remove array[0], array[1] will still be the same and the random generating number can still roll 0 which will then return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Object[] array = new Object[10];    // say 10 objects
int remain = array.length;
Random rnd = new Random();

public Object next () {
    if (remain == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int i = rnd.nextInt(remain--);
        Object tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[remain];
        array[remain] = tmp;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

This will generate next random question

Comment: Would i have to put all the questions in the array first?

Comment: and therefore to out put the question its textViewQuestions.setText(next());?

Comment: This returns type object, but it needs to be type string to display the results in view

Comment: Just replace Object with String , that's it

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, with

```
            getQuestions();
            String n = String.valueOf(next());
            textViewQuestions.setText(n);
```

I also populated the array like this

```
for (i = 0; i < questionsJson.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = questionsJson.getJSONObject(i);
                        array[i] = object.getString("question");
                        questionList.add(object.getString("question"));
                        Log.d(TAG,object.getString("question"));


                    }
```

However, the questions do repeat but will only show a set amount of questions. :( How to make the questions not repeat?

Comment: The repetition in the code was fixed, the logic remain true